# Lua autoclicker not repeating

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to write an autoclicker in logitech G hub, which uses lua. I'm currently using the code below.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then 
      repeat 
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(51, 60)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

However, it won't repeat. The only thing that works is to get rid of the not in line 7, but then it repeats forever, and won't stop. I do have the older version of g hub, and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this logitech functionality, but I was thinking, maybe you are clicking mouse button 5 during the sleep time. What if you remove the `not` and then try holding mouse button 5 down, to make sure it is pressed at the end of a loop

Answer (score 0):

You should restore the default binding of G5 mouse button (its default action is "forward" command) at the "assignments" page.

Comment: I have. I forgot to mention that it is only the repeat function that doesn't work, not the macro itself. It runs once fine, but nothing else.